# if condition in awk script

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I have one details.txt file which has below data

```
size=190000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload
repo-path=/home/test/testupload
size=140000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload2
repo-path=/home/test/testupload2
size=170000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload3
repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
```

and so on

and below awk script process that to

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -vOFS='\t' '
BEGIN{ FS="=" }
/^size/{
  if(++count1==1){ header=$1"," }
  sizeArr[++count]=$NF
  next
}
/^@repo-name/{
  if(++count2==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
  repoNameArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
/^date/{
  if(++count3==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
  dateArr[count]=$NF
  next
  }
/^@blob-name/{
  if(++count4==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
  repopathArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
END{
  print header
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",sizeArr[i],repoNameArr[i],dateArr[i],repopathArr[i])
  }
}
' details.txt | tr -d @ |awk -F, '{$3=substr($3,0,10)}1' OFS=,|sed 's/date/creationTime/g'
```

which prints value well formatted

```
size    date            repo-name          repo-path
190000  1603278566981   testupload      /home/test/testupload
140000  1603278566981   testupload2     /home/test/testupload2
170000  1603278566981   testupload3     /home/test/testupload3
```

I want to add if when any of the size/date/repo-name/repo-path  has no value it should print zero instead

I tried to add below in awk script but it is not working, I dont know how to get that

```
}
/^@repo-name/{
  if(++count2==1){ header=header OFS $1"," }
          if(-z "${repo-name}") ; then
  repoNameArr=0
  repoNameArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
```

I am not sure how to use if in awk script, can you please help me here

final output should be printing zero if there is no value against  size/date/repo-name/repo-path

```
size    date            repo-name          repo-path
190000  1603278566981   testupload      /home/test/testupload
140000  1603278566981   testupload2     /home/test/testupload2
170000  1603278566981   testupload3     /home/test/testupload3
170000  1603278566981   0               /home/test/testupload4
170000  1603278566981   0               /home/test/testupload5
170000  1603278566981   testupload6     /home/test/testupload6
```

please guide

Comment: Please [edit] the example in your question to include the case you want to implement, i.e. `any of the size/date/repo-name/repo-path has no value`, as that could mean a couple of different things (e.g. `date=` or no `date=` line at all) and make sure the expected output you post is the output you expect from the input you post, not from some other input, so we can copy/paste it to test with.

Comment: Your code doesn't run - there are too many `%s` parameters on line 26 for the arguments supplied. Also note that none of your example data will match the two conditions containing an `@` symbol

Comment: Your code can in no way to produce the output you claim

Answer (score 2):

You may set the last field to zero if it's empty using

```c
if ($NF == "") $NF = 0
```

So you'd get something like

```c
/^@repo-name/ {
  if (++count2 == 1) header = header OFS $1 ","
  if ($NF == "") $NF = 0

  repoNameArr[count] = $NF
  next
}
```

or, to avoid repeating code,

```c
$NF == "" { $NF = 0 }

# ...

/^@repo-name/ {
  if (++count2 == 1) header = header OFS $1 ","
  repoNameArr[count] = $NF
  next
}
```

(Note that no line in your data matches `^@repo-name`.)

---

In this case, I would probably go for a simpler approach.  Assuming that each record is always four lines, we may rearrange the data into four tab-delimited columns using `paste`:

```bash
$ cat file
size=
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload
repo-path=/home/test/testupload
size=140000
date=
repo-name=testupload2
repo-path=/home/test/testupload2
size=170000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=
repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
size=170000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload3
repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
```

```bash
$ paste - - - - <file
size=   date=1603278566981      repo-name=testupload    repo-path=/home/test/testupload
size=140000     date=   repo-name=testupload2   repo-path=/home/test/testupload2
size=170000     date=1603278566981      repo-name=      repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
size=170000     date=1603278566981      repo-name=testupload3   repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
```

This can then be transformed into CSV using `mlr` ([Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```bash
$ paste - - - - <file | mlr --ifs tab --ocsv cat
size,date,repo-name,repo-path
,1603278566981,testupload,/home/test/testupload
140000,,testupload2,/home/test/testupload2
170000,1603278566981,,/home/test/testupload3
170000,1603278566981,testupload3,/home/test/testupload3
```

We may also use `mlr` to replace any missing values with zero:

```bash
$ paste - - - - <file | mlr --ifs tab --ocsv put 'for (k,v in $*) { is_null(v) { $[k] = 0 } }'
size,date,repo-name,repo-path
0,1603278566981,testupload,/home/test/testupload
140000,0,testupload2,/home/test/testupload2
170000,1603278566981,0,/home/test/testupload3
170000,1603278566981,testupload3,/home/test/testupload3
```

Would you want tab-separated values (TSV) in place of CSV, then use `--otsv` in place of `--ocsv`.  You can get "pretty printed" tabular output with `--opprint`, or JSON with `--ojson`, or whatever you need.

Note that the above assumes the input data looks like in the question.  If the data in the question is a proccesed variant of some data in a structured data format such as XML or JSON, then it would be far better to work with that original data directly.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes that when you say `any of the size/date/repo-name/repo-path has no value` you mean. for example, that `repo-name=` is present, not that there is no `repo-name=` line at all in some blocks.

Here's how to really do what you're trying to do using any awk and then `column` for the final column spacing:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    sub(/^@/,"")                  # instead of `| tr -d @`
    ++numTags
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/ *=.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^=]+= */,"",val)
    tags[numTags] = tag
    vals[numTags] = val
}
numTags == 4 {
    if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=numTags; i++ ) {
            tag = ( tags[i] == "date" ? "creationTime" : tags[i] )  # instead of `| sed s/date/creationTime/`
            printf "%s%s", tag, (i<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    vals[3] = substr(vals[3],1,10)     # instead of `| awk {$3=substr($3,0,10}1`
    for ( i=1; i<=numTags; i++ ) {
        val = ( vals[i] == "" ? 0 : vals[i] )
        printf "%s%s", val, (i<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    numTags = 0
}
' "${@:--}" |
column -s$'\t' -t
```

```
$ cat file
size=190000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload
repo-path=
size=140000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=
repo-path=/home/test/testupload2
size=
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload3
repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
size    creationTime   repo-name    repo-path
190000  1603278566981  testupload   0
140000  1603278566981  0            /home/test/testupload2
0       1603278566981  testupload3  /home/test/testupload3
```

The changes from your existing code:

1. `awk` no longer has to read the whole file into memory at once. I suspect `column` has to do that to figure out the spacing though. If you don't have `column` THEN awk would have to read all the input into memory as we'd use a 2-pass approach to figure out the max length of the fields in each column before outputting using `printf` and those max field widths.
2. It no longer depends on values in your data (except I added in the mapping of `date` to `creationTime` in the header line that you're currently doing with a pipe to sed), it just relies on there being 4 lines at a time of data. Easily changed to trigger off hitting a specific tag line if that's more useful, e.g. just change `numTags == 4` to `tag == "repo-path"`.
3. It no longer pipes to `sed` to change the `date` column header to `creatingTime` because, in addition to an extra pipe and command just not being necessary, that would break if your input contained the string `date` anywhere, e.g. `repo-path=/home/date/uploadX`
4. It no longer uses `=` as the FS value because doing so would fail if any of your input contained `=`, , e.g. `repo-path=/home/foo=bar/uploadX`,
5. If you want to remove all `@`s from your data the way to do that would be
   with `gsub(/@/,"")`, not pipe the output to `tr -d @`, but I think you really only want to do that for the header names (tags) otherwise it'll break if any of your data insludes `@`s, e.g. `repo-path=/home/foo@bar/uploadX`, so I included `sub(/^@/,"")` to do only remove `@`s from the start of tags.
6. If you want to trim the 3rd field to 10 chars, the way to do that is with `substr(vals[3],1,10)` before the loop that's printing `vals[]`, not add a pipe to a second awk script, so I included that. The 2nd arg for `substr()` starts at `1` btw, not `0`.